# GDAL - Python27 - Text to shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, convert, text

I've been looking for a way to convert txt file columns to shapefile's. With the code below I am able to divide txt columns, what I don't know is how to store all those columns in a point shapefile, any idea? I am still looking for the answer.

```
f = open(txtRuta)
contents = f.read()
f.close()
new_contents = contents.replace('\n', ' ')
new_contents = new_contents.strip(' ')

f = open(txtRuta, 'w')
f.write(new_contents)
f.close()

new_contents = re.sub(r" + ", " ",  new_contents)

itemsInString = new_contents.split(" ")
lon= ((len(itemsInString)/9))

idx = []
aa = []
gpstime = []
x = []
y = []
z = []
bb = []
cc = []
dd = []

numbeer = 0

for index, item in enumerate(itemsInString):
    if numbeer == 9:
        numbeer = 0

    if numbeer == 0:
        idx.append(int(item))
    elif numbeer == 1:
        aa.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 2:
        gpstime.append(int(item))
    elif numbeer == 3:
        x.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 4:
        y.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 5:
        z.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 6:
        bb.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 7:
        cc.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 8:
        dd.append(float(item))
    numbeer = numbeer + 1
for i in range(0, lon):

    line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    line.AddPoint(x[i], y[i], z[i])
    print line.ExportToWkt()
```

EDIT:

From GDAL/OGR cookbook, code below works for .txt to .shp, configure it as you need it.

```
f = open(txtRuta)
contents = f.read()
f.close()
new_contents = contents.replace('\n', ' ')
new_contents = new_contents.strip(' ')

f = open(txtRuta, 'w')
f.write(new_contents)
f.close()

new_contents = re.sub(r" + ", " ",  new_contents)

itemsInString = new_contents.split(" ")
lon= ((len(itemsInString)/9))

idx = []
aa = []
gpstime = []
x = []
y = []
z = []
bb = []
cc = []
dd = []
larg = len(idx)

numbeer = 0

for index, item in enumerate(itemsInString):
    if numbeer == 9:
        numbeer = 0

    if numbeer == 0:
        idx.append(int(item))
    elif numbeer == 1:
        aa.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 2:
        gpstime.append(int(item))
    elif numbeer == 3:
        x.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 4:
        y.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 5:
        z.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 6:
        bb.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 7:
        cc.append(float(item))
    elif numbeer == 8:
        dd.append(float(item))
    numbeer = numbeer + 1

shpout = shpRuta + "\\" + pNombre + ".shp"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(shpout)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(int(epsgUse))

layer = data_source.CreateLayer(pNombre, srs, ogr.wkbPoint)

layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTInteger))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("aa", ogr.OFTReal))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("gpstime", ogr.OFTInteger))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("x", ogr.OFTReal))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("y", ogr.OFTReal))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("z", ogr.OFTReal))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("bb", ogr.OFTReal))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("cc", ogr.OFTReal))
layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("dd", ogr.OFTReal))


for i in range(0, lon):

    feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
    feature.SetField("id", idx[i])
    feature.SetField("aa", aa[i])
    feature.SetField("gpstime", gpstime[i])
    feature.SetField("x", x[i])
    feature.SetField("y", y[i])
    feature.SetField("z", z[i])
    feature.SetField("bb", bb[i])
    feature.SetField("cc", cc[i])
    feature.SetField("dd", dd[i])

    wkt = "POINT(%f %f)" % (float(x[i]) , float(y[i]))

    point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)

    feature.SetGeometry(point)
    layer.CreateFeature(feature)
    feature.Destroy()

data_source.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy once you have discovered the [Python OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html).

- Here is how to [read in a CSV file](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#read-a-csv-of-coordinates-as-an-ogrvrtlayer).
- Here is how to [write a point
  shapefile](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-point-shapefile-with-attribute-data).

sticking to two together is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote, but I finished it... Is it ok if I edit my post with the fully working version so anyone struggling can use it?